# schtasks.exe cannot see all tasks on a remore host

Tags: remote-control, windows-task-scheduler

I run into the problem while getting scheduled tasks on a remote host.

schtasks.exe /QUERY /S

Command above shows only tasks stored in c:\Windows\Tasks
but not in c:\Windows\System\Tasks.

The user has an admin access on the remote host.

Comment: Are you connecting to the remote computer using an account that has administrator privileges (on that remote machine)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, yes.